# vscode pull request extension for bitbucket

Tags: visual-studio-code, bitbucket

The FAQ for the VSCODE bitbucket extension says that BitBucket support might come later as a fork of the original extension.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github/wiki

But I do see that Atlassian seemed to be working on such a fork but the repository is now archived:

https://github.com/atlassian/vscode-pull-request-bitbucket

Any idea if there is any movement here, or alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesterday this extension was released.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Atlassian.atlascode#overview

Version
1.0.0
Released on
2/22/2019, 11:36:08 PM

Official extension from Atlassian.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Bitbucket-pull-request-integration-with-VS-Code/qaq-p/967181

Comment: @Yuril Any way this can be used with locally hosted Jira & Bitbucket instances?

Comment: @Dr.YSG Unfortunately not.
This extension is only available for Jira and Bitbucket Cloud today.
But as I understand there is some plans.
Please look at Atlassian community, link in my answer.